# Firestore join user to its collection data in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, join, google-cloud-firestore

i want to join user to its datas. In my code below, i can read the data from firestore, but when i try to show the data into table, I only got a post of user's post. Although users have more then one post in posts collection.

[image]

In my `console.log('this is userData:', userData)`, it shows
`this is userData: [{...}]` and `this is userData: (2) [{...}, {...}]`

in my `{userData.map((post, index) => {console.log(index, post)})}`, the post index is 0 for all post.

may be i missed something in here, how can i fix this?

```
export default function App () {

    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
    console.log('this is userData:', userData);

    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection('user').doc('idUser').onSnapshot((documentSnaphot) => {
            const posts = [];
            for (let id in documentSnaphot.data().userPosts) {
                db.collection('post').doc(id).onSnapshot((docSnapshot) => {
                    posts.push(docSnapshot.data());
                    setUserData(posts);
                })
            }
        })
    }, []);

    return (
       {userData.map((post, index) => {
           console.log(index, post);
       })}
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use `get` instead of a realtime listener and `async/await` to make the code more clear:

```js
export default function App({ userUid }) {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
  const [posts, setUserPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("user")
      .doc(userUid)
      .onSnapshot((snap) => {
        setUserData(snap.data());
      });
  }, [userUid]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const posts = [];
    for (let id in userData.userPosts) {
      const postSnap = await db.collection("posts").doc(id).get();
      posts.push(postSnap.data());
    }
    setUserPosts(posts);
  }, [userData]);

  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map((post, index) => {
        console.log(index, post);
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you need a realtime listener let me know and I will update the code to have one.

Comment: Yes i need realtime listener , thanks for helping me...

Comment: Do you need it for both? User data and posts?

Comment: {userData.map((post, index) => { console.log(index, post); })} i got error, map is not a function

Comment: only for the posts

Comment: I have updated the answer. Actualy we need to listen to the user data if we want to add new posts. Each post probably wont change during time.

Comment: Thanks bro... I'm a newbe, your answer is very helpful

Comment: Happy to hear it helped :)